# JCreator Cannot find symbol very simple

Tags: java, symbols, jcreator

This is obviously not the entire code but this is the problem im having. Its supposed to write random numbers between 0 and whatever i put in ((x))).

```
for (int i=0; i<1; i=i+1){
int tal2 = 1 +
            (int)(Math.random () * ((9)));
System.out.print("" + tal2);
}
for (int i=0; i<1; i=i+1){
int tal3 = 1 +
            (int)(Math.random () * ((1)));
System.out.print("" + tal3);
}
if (tal3==1){
for (int i=0; i<1; i=1+1){
int tal4 = 1 +
            (int)(Math.random () * ((2)));
System.out.print("" + tal4);
}
}
else if (tal3==0)
for (int i=0; i<1; i=i+1){
int tal4 = 1 +
            (int)(Math.random () * ((9)));
System.out.print("" + tal4);
```

error: cannot find symbol
    if (tal3==1){
        ^
error: cannot find symbol
    else if (tal3==0)

Comment: You declare tab3 inside the loop. so you can not use it outside the loop.

Comment: You should clean up and indent your code.
The third for loop has `i=1+1(= 2)` as the recurring statement, this appears to be unintentional.

Comment: @AlexR yeah oops. But it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the working answer.

```
class Hello    
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   int tal2;
   int tal3 =0;
   int tal4 =0;
for (int i=0; i<1; i=i+1){
tal2 = 1 +(int)(Math.random () * ((9)));
System.out.print("" + tal2);
}
for (int i=0; i<1; i=i+1){
tal3 = 1 +(int)(Math.random () * ((1)));
System.out.print("\n" + tal3);
}
if (tal3==1){
for (int i=0; i<1; i=i+1){
 tal4 = 1 +(int)(Math.random () * ((2)));
System.out.print("\n" + tal4);
}
}
else if (tal3==0)
for (int i=0; i<1; i=i+1){
 tal4 = 1 +(int)(Math.random () * ((9)));
System.out.print("\n" + tal4);

}
}
}
```